# Unable to select dropdown with search box in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dropdown box HTML:

```
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-country-container">
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-country-container" title=""
</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b>
</span>
</span>
```

For dropdown option Denmark=>

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Denmark</li>
```

I am unable to select the dropdown by Select class as there no Select is present. How to select the dropdown and how to search in the searchbox ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAKTm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to click on the dropdown to expand it, then click on the option you wish to select, using some selector like XPath or CSS, rather than using the select class.

Here's how I would select the option `Denmark` from the dropdown you provided:

```
# click combobox to expand it
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@role='combobox']").click()

# wait for "Denmark" option to appear
denmark_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Denmark']")))

# select the "Denmark" option
denmark_option.click()
```